# Is there way to hide/rename a plugin used on my wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is there is a way for me to change or hide a specific plugin I'm using on a Wordpress website? I'm curious if there is a way to hide plugins for example `wpthemedetector` or from the source code?

Comment: what exactly the mean of hide plugin ?????????

Comment: Hide plugin name from source code or wpthemedetector..

Comment: you can edit plugin source code for change it's name ..... for remove(hide) it from wordpress list you never can do that because wordpress automatically find installed plugins in plugins filder and list them.

Comment: @ArashHatami , that's incorrect. You *can* hide an item from the list

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a plugin from the plugin list using the [`all_plugins` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/all_plugins/):

> Filter the full array of plugins to list in the Plugins list table.

Unfortunately, that's as specific as I can get without seeing your attempt at this first.